# Is it possible to ask for a certain amount of inputs and do something with them in a single stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Right now, I have a program that asks the user for how many strings they will input, and then I use an `IntStream` to go through that many and add each one to a List.

```
final List<String> patterns = new ArrayList<>();

final int testCaseNumber = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

IntStream.range(0, testCaseNumber).forEach(i -> patterns.add(scan.nextLine()));
```

Then, I have another stream operation that does something else  over this list.

```
patterns.stream().forEach(pattern -> doSomething());
```

Is there a way to skip the use of the patterns `List` entirely, and just directly go from the `IntStream` to the final `forEach()` statement?

I've tried using `mapToObj()` and `peek()`, but neither works in the way I want them to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just have

```
IntStream.range(0, testCaseNumber)
         .mapToObj(i -> scan.nextLine())
         .forEach(input -> doSomething(input));
```

This creates an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) going from 0 to the wanted number of inputs and maps each of those into what the user is entering with [`mapToObj`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj-java.util.function.IntFunction-).

On the other hand, if you want to first collect all inputs and process them afterwards then you will have to store those:

```
List<String> inputs =
    IntStream.range(0, testCaseNumber)
             .mapToObj(i -> scan.nextLine())
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
// ...
inputs.forEach(input -> doSomething(input));
```

Note that in this case, there is really no particular reason to use the Stream API and you're probably better off using a simple `for` loop.